# typedef unknown in derived class

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, typedef

I'm trying to write a container adaptor. I want to use the type definitions from the base class in the derived class as well. So I have tried the following...

```
template <class CONTAINER> class SequenceComposite {
protected:
    CONTAINER m_data;
public:
    typedef typename CONTAINER::size_type size_type;
    // ...
};

template <class DTYPE>
class VectorComposite : public virtual SequenceComposite< std::vector<DTYPE> > {
public:
    size_type capacity() const { m_data.capacity(); }
    // ...
};
```

I got this error...

```
error: ‘size_type’ does not name a type  
note: (perhaps ‘typename SequenceComposite<std::vector<T> >::size_type’ was intended) // yes, it was
```

How do I tell the compiler that I want to use the typedef from the base class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to get this to work, here is a good article on [Dependent name lookup for C++ templates](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/02/06/dependent-name-lookup-for-c-templates/) and [this](http://womble.decadent.org.uk/c++/template-faq.html#base-lookup) covers how to fix the issue with `m_data`:

```
template <class DTYPE>
class VectorComposite : public virtual SequenceComposite< std::vector<DTYPE> >     
{
public:
     typedef typename SequenceComposite< std::vector<DTYPE> >::size_type size_type ;

     size_type capacity() const
        {
          this->m_data.capacity() ;
        }
    // ...
};
```

Alternatively you can also use `using`:

```
using typename SequenceComposite< std::vector<DTYPE> >::size_type ;
```

Although I don't think that makes it much better, `jrok` suggested an even better solution:

```
 typename VectorComposite::size_type capacity() const
 {
    this->m_data.capacity() ;
 }
```

Comment: Hmm ... this was not intended. This would mean to redefine all types that already have been defined.

Comment: @Michael You can also use `using`, I added that example as well.

Comment: @Michael The solution suggested by `jrok` is even better

Comment: Inerestingly `class MyModel : public virtual VectorComposite<double> { public:     explicit MyModel(size_type n) : VectorComposite<double>(n) {} };`
works, without redefining `size_type`

Comment: @Michael That is because it is not templated, if you did template <class DTYPE> class MyModel .... then you would have the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

In the context of the derived type, `size_type` is a non-dependent name, and as such it will be looked up in the context of the template without instantiating base templates. If you need to use it, the simplest thing is to *clone* the typedef in the derived type:

```
typename VectorComposite::size_type size_type; // [*]
```

<sup>[*]</sup> Following jrok's fix to the original incorrect code.

Comment: Am I missing something I was not able to get that syntax to work, I have to use the syntax in my example in order for it to work.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour: you are right, the injected name cannot be used directly. Removing the answer.

Comment: I would just amend it, your initial explanation was much better than mine was.

Comment: `typedef typename VectorComposite::size_type size_type;` does work, though.

Comment: @jrok: That works, with our without the typename, as it transforms the non-dependent name into a dependent name, lookup is postponed to the second phase after argument substitution and the base type will be looked up.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas I hoped that I could avoid the cloning

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas jrok's solution works for me only with 'typename'

Answer (score 1):

Put base's `size_type` in this way:

```
typename SequenceComposite<std::vector<DTYPE>>::size_type capacity() const{ //..
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: `typename VectorComposite::size_type capacity() const { this->m_data.capacity(); }` works as well